# Javascript: Upload image on bigger background, then crop it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image, crop

In my application, I need my images to be 500x360. I wanna provide an upload form to allow the user to pick a picture, resize it to the desired format, then send it to the server.

Very simple for widescreen images. I have trouble with the other sizes - more height than width. With every cropping tool I tried, there's no way for me to squeeze the complete image inside the canvas since it is limited by the width.

You can try it here. I don't know how to fit the bottle inside the canvas.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeLvJm

```
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
      viewport: {
          width: 500,
          height: 360,
          type: 'square'
      },
      boundary: {
          width: 600,
          height: 400
      },
      enforceBoundary: false
  });
```

Load this image: http://www.lcbo.com/content/dam/lcbo/products/000067.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.web.1280.1280.jpeg

I tried many libraries without success: croppie, cropper, angular-image-cropper, ngImgCrop...

I thought about setting a canvas 900x900, upload my image in the middle, then fiddle with it to crop it the way I like, but I am not sure on how I should proceed.

Generic directions / Library would be appreciated (jquery / angular if possible).

Thank you !

Comment: So, you are trying to fit the whole image inside the rectangular area, right? And add background in no-image areas?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what i'm trying to do. Every cropping library i've tried won't leave the boundary of the container, so i'm missing some part of the image. I would like to fit the image in the rectangular area, then fill in white the "missing" parts